# How to access a method defined inside a class from another method outside the class

Tags: python, oop

```
def my_func():
    x = Loader.__get_classes_from_module("string","string") # this line causes an error

class Loader(object):
    def get_tests(self, test_prefix="", tags=None, exclude=False):
        # code here

    @staticmethod
    def __get_classes_from_module(f, prefix_class_name=None):
        # code here
```

In the above code, I get an error stating that AttributeError: type object 'Loader' has no attribute '__get_classes_from_module'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You put two underscores.

Comment: You should call it with `Loader._Loader__get_classes_from_module`.

Comment: Because of [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references), your method `__get_classes_from_module` is not actually accessible from outside the class by that name. Considering you want to use it from outside the object itself, you might want to drop the two leading underscores and just call it `get_classes_from_module`.